# PSU coil whine, black screen & loud gpu fan (need help)

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

As of 1 week ago my computer started having some really weird coil whine coming from the PSU, and my monitor became black a few times and you could hear the GPU fans go 100%, so i instantly went and dusted the whole thing, after that the gpu problem happened again 3 times now, usually about once a day, and when i turned on the computer today, i had to do a disk check.
 I've also experienced some random lag on my computer.
 the specs are:
 GPU:AMD Raedon HD5850
 CPU : intel i5 2500K
 8 GB Ram
 motherboard:gigabyte H61M-S2PV
 the psu is LC power 550W, they are widely spread in europe.

Any help is greatly appreciated because i think the psu is bad and its damaging all my other components, so i want to act fast, but dont know what to replace or do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you descibe sounds more like a GPU load occuring, and the GPU failing, and going into recovery.
So while it could still be the PSU not providing enough power for the gpu, this same occurance could just be the many ways that a GPU could drop out.  Fan not running fast enough, for the temps. Power going high on the GPU (coil whine) during that. and the fail and recover. Ram chips getting too hot, and other GPU minor issues.  (minor because so far you can still get it working again)

Tests:
 start testing by going into the CCC, taking the GPU fan off of automatic, and having it run at a fairly high manual rate.
Find some way to check the GPU temps , then hard test the GPU with furmark or some other vicious GPU testing software.   (do not hard test without temperature monitoring)
The Obvious, if it was overclocked or over voltaged in any way, stop that at least until you have tested.

If it breaks when the temps are reading normal on the GPU, and the Ram on the GPU is properly being cooled, and it breaks when you go to play 3D games, and the temps are reading ok still, then suspect the PSU.

If instead temps are not stable, and raising the fan to "way too loud" is effectivly cooling the gpu and stopping the problem.  Then get some stuff to re-do the GPU cooling.  Ram Pads, Thermal Goop, and screwdriver set, and possibly a new fan, possibly a new cooler set.  Then dissasemble the GPU carefully and re-do the thermal interfaces, and clean the heat sync completly.  Carefully reassemble and plop it in and test again.

The GPU failing could  take out the rest of the system sometimes, but the PSU not providing enough power should more often take out the whole rest of the system, not just do a black screen some fan whining and back on again.  That is why I am suggeting to test first.

Comment: the temps are 66 idle and about 80 in game, usually it shuts down in games

Comment: That is not really extreme temperatures although with the RAM getting hotter sometimes, that could be it. I would want to prove it better or just fix it and see if that worked.